# Use the swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens method of uniswap routerV2 to purchase uniswap V3pair tokens

Tags: web3js, uniswap, uniswapv3, uniswapv2

```
const buyToken = async (account: any, tokenContract: any, gasLimit: any, gasPrice: any) => {
  let amountOutMin = 0;
  const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits(useBuy.value.toString(), 'ether');
  if (Slippage.value !== 0) {
    const amounts = await router(account).getAmountsOut(amountIn, [config.WETH.address, tokenContract]);
    amountOutMin = amounts[1].sub(amounts[1].mul(Slippage.value).div(100))
  }
  const tx = await router(account).swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
      amountOutMin,
      [config.WETH.address, tokenContract],
      account.address,
      (Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10),
      {
        'value': amountIn,
        'gasLimit': gasLimit,
        'gasPrice': gasPrice,
      }
  );
  const receipt = await tx.wait();
```

Using swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens to buy currency with V2 Pair is valid, no problem, but if you buy currency with V3 Pair, an error will be reported.
[image]

How to solve this problem?
Before, I didn’t know whether the user wanted to buy a V2 pair or a V3 pair. If there is a currency that has a pair in V2 but is not active, the actual active pair is the V3 pair. How should I deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens is a v2 router function, v2 router doesn't know anything about the v3 pools, the pool methods and arguments are also totally different. v3 doesn't support tax on transfer tokens.

 Use a function from the v3 router, universal router, or the pool directly.

ex.

```py
AMOUNT_OUT = 1*10**18
SQRT_PRICE_LIMIT = 0
FEE = 500

amount_in = quoter.functions.quoteExactOutputSingle(TOKEN_IN, TOKEN_OUT, FEE, AMOUNT_OUT, SQRT_PRICE_LIMIT).call()
multiplier = 0.01 # 1% slippage
AMOUNT_IN_WITH_SLIPPAGE = amount_in + round(multiplier * amount_in)

DEADLINE = 2000000000
#...
params = (TOKEN_IN, TOKEN_OUT, FEE, EOA, DEADLINE, AMOUNT_OUT, AMOUNT_IN_WITH_SLIPPAGE, SQRT_PRICE_LIMIT)
#...
swap = router.functions.exactOutputSingle(params).build_transaction(tx)
```